# iOS Using Partial Page Curl on UIView, NOT UIViewController

Tags: ios, animation, curl, uiview

I've got a MainViewController that has many subViews. Basically, it's broken down into two panes. The panes are designed to look like clipboards. I'd like to hit a button and have the "paper" on one of the clipboards do a partial curl to reveal the page underneath.

This isn't a full Modal ViewController presentation situation.

I'm working with the following code, but the results are funky:

```
    FlipView *flipView = [[FlipView alloc] init];
    [self setFlipView:flipView];
    [flipView setHidden:YES];
    [flipView setFrame:[[self WhereAmI] frame]];
    [[self view] addSubview:flipView];
    [[self view] bringSubviewToFront:[self WhereAmI]];
    [flipView setHidden:NO];
    CATransition *animation = [CATransition animation];
    [animation setDelegate:self];
    [animation setDuration:1.0];
    [animation setTimingFunction:[CAMediaTimingFunction functionWithName:kCAMediaTimingFunctionEaseInEaseOut]];
    [animation setType:@"pageCurl"];
    [animation setFillMode:kCAFillModeForwards];
    [animation setEndProgress:0.9];
    [animation setRemovedOnCompletion:NO];
    [[self WhereAmI] setHidden:YES];
    [[[self WhereAmI] layer] addAnimation:animation forKey:@"pageCurlAnimation"];
```

Basically, I'm trying to load my new view programmatically, slide it in behind the currently visible view and then curl up the view that's on top to reveal the view that's now underneath. I get somewhat of a partial curl animation, but the "page" that's curling up isn't opaque, which is odd. Also, when I don't set my view and label to be hidden, even though you see them curl up, you also still see them "underneath", which is also odd. Plus, I don't see the UILabel I placed in the XIB for the new view.

Any thoughts?

Thanks!

---

OK, so I've got a working solution, but it's not quite what I was hoping to do. I'd still love to figure out the solution to my original question, but here's what I'm doing for now:

1. The background image for my "base" view is an image of a spiral-bound notebook.
2. The background image for all other views is a screen shot of a page curl.
   (By "background image", I mean a UIColor created with a patternImage.)
3. The code to transition views is:

   ```
   - (IBAction)NavigationTabSelected:(id)sender 
   {
       // Flipping views is driven by a SegmentedControl
       int selected = [[self NavigationTabsSegmentedControl] selectedSegmentIndex];
       int current = [[self ViewArray] indexOfObject:[self ActiveFlipView]];
       UIView *newFlip = [[self ViewArray] objectAtIndex:selected];

       BOOL up = selected > current;
       [UIView animateWithDuration:1.0
                        animations:^{
                            [UIView setAnimationTransition:(up)?UIViewAnimationTransitionCurlUp:UIViewAnimationTransitionCurlDown forView:[self RightView] cache:YES];
                            [[self ActiveFlipView] removeFromSuperview];
                            [[self RightView] addSubview:newFlip];
                        }
                        completion:^(BOOL finished){
                            [self setActiveFlipView:newFlip];
                        }];
   }
   ```

As you can see, tabs to the right of the current tab generate a "curl up" and tabs to the left of the current tab generate a "curl down". It's not quite what I wanted, but it serves my purpose.

Any better ideas?

Comment: Have you seen UIView's `transitionFromView` and `transitionWithView` methods? You should be able to do what you want in 2-3 lines of code.

Answer (score -3):

have you considered loading it as a modal view?

```
- (void)yourFrontViewControllerMethod
{
    YourBackViewController *bfvc = [[YourBackViewController alloc] init];
    [bfvc setModalTransitionStyle:UIMoalTransitionStylePartialCurl];
    [self presentViewController:bfvc];
    [bvfc release];
}
```

This will give you the desired effect of a view curling up to reveal another view.

Also as a general rule of thumb we try not to create animations that way. Try using a block based method instead  (eg [UIView AnimateWithDuration:....]);

Hope that helps :)

Comment: Yes, I've considered this, but isn't this method only valid when doing a full-page partial curl? I'm not sure if it was unclear above, but I'm only wanting to curl up PART of my screen. Also, I did my animations as shown above so that I could control the EndProgress value, since completing the animation I use would take the page completely off-screen.

Comment: -1 Since your answer completely missed the "this isn't a full modal situation" in my original post.